# Search in tag aware sharding for non-key attributes?

Tags: mongodb

How search occurs in tag aware sharding for non-key attributes?
Will it search  for all clusters, or it will automatically search from local shard?
What is the process behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-internals/#query-isolation and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/  But yes, if the mongos router doesn't know on which shard a document lives, then it will issue a "scatter gather" query to all shards to run the query. It will then also merge the results that come back. The presentation at http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/sharding-15392976 (slides 38-56) explain it as well with some diagrams.